# dropping tablespace throws error ORA-02429: cannot drop index used for enforcement of unique/primary key in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, indexing, database-partitioning, tablespace

I wanted to drop a tablespace that stores index.

```
drop tablespace THR_TBS_IDX INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;
```

And this is the error I got

```
Error report -
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-02429: cannot drop index used for enforcement of unique/primary key
00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
           (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
*Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
           can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.
```

I tried to see what indexes is blocking the deletion, but it returned no records from the following sql statement. I do not know what in the tablespace is stopping the deletion

```
 select owner, constraint_name,table_name,index_owner,index_name
from dba_constraints
where (index_owner,index_name) in (select owner,index_name from dba_indexes
where tablespace_name='THR_TBS_IDX');
```

Need some help here to figure out how to drop this tablespace successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Purdge recycle bin.
then disable it
and only after this you can drop you TB

Answer (score 0):

ORA-02429 means that the index you want to drop is a primary key.
Although primary key is an index its also a constraint. You should treat it like a constraint first then drop it as an index.
first we drop the constraint.
Then drop the index